# Why does the setEmotion function get printed each time I click on a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is only one console log statement and I am not calling App() each time (from what I know). Why is the console log statement ran each time a button is pressed?

```
import './App.css';
import React, {useState} from "react";

function App() {
  const [emotion, setEmotion] = useState("happy");
  console.log(emotion, setEmotion)
  return(
    <>
   <h1>Current emotion is {emotion}</h1>
   <button onClick={() => setEmotion("sad")}>Sad</button>
   <button onClick={() => setEmotion("angry")}>Angry</button>
   <button onClick={() => setEmotion("happy")}>Happy</button>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Because you invoke it on every click by binding it to `onClick`...

Comment: App is a react component. If its being rendered, reacts takes care of calling the function and displaying its return value onto the screen. This happens when either state or props is changed. Since emotion is a state, setEmotion changes the state and react reevalates the function.

Comment: @msanford, the console.log prints the actual function (which is an object). It doesn't run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `console.log` is executed each time because you're updating the component's state on each button click.

You've created a function component `App` which executes itself whenever it needs to be (re-)rendered. That render happens whenever any of its state (in this case `emotion`) was updated, which in turn happens when clicking any of the buttons.

The reason `emotion` doesn't reset on each render is that React internally keeps track of its value and it will only update `emotion` whenever `setEmotion` is called. The initial value of `"happy"` is only considered on the first render.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that. Where did you learn that?